# Print statement working in function but not in body of the code

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Python beginner here

I`m writing a script to solve sudoku. Most of the code is taken from this video.

The function works and prints the solved grid as long as my print statement is in the function, but when I put it outside the function it prints out the original array and not the solved array.

Any idea why this is happening and on how can I access the solved array outside the function in the body of the code.

You all can ignore testing the functions because they work as the solved array is getting printed from the function, my problem is how to get it printed and access it from the body.

I would like print statements 3 or 4 to be the solved array.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np

sudoku_grid = np.array([[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 3, 7],
                         [0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 1],
                         [0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                         [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0],
                         [6, 0, 8, 9, 0, 5, 3, 0, 4],
                         [0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
                         [0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0],
                         [7, 8, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                         [2, 3, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]])

def possible(row, column, number, grid):
    """Checks whether a number can be inserted in a cell"""

    # Checking for duplicate number in row
    for i in range(9):
        if number == grid[row, i]:
            return False

    # Checking for duplicate number in column
    for j in range(9):
        if number == grid[j, column]:
            return False

    # Checking for duplicate number in grid
    # Returns 0,1,2 for row and column so basically 9X9 grid is reduced to 3X3 grid         
  and duplicated are checked within the same
    r = row//3*3
    c = column//3*3

    for k in range(r, r+3):
        for l in range(c, c+3):
            if number == grid[k, l]:
                return False

    return True


def solve(grid):
    """Solves sudoku using recursion and back tracking"""

    # use combination of row and column to get a cell
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):

            # if cell is zero then tries to enter number
            if grid[i, j] == 0:
                for k in range(1, 10):

                    # Checks if number is possible and enters the same in array
                    if possible(i, j, k, grid):
                        grid[i, j] = k

                        # Recursion moves to next cell
                        solve(grid)

                        # Backtracks if not possible
                        grid[i, j] = 0

                # if no numbers are 0 then Solved and return array
                return grid
    print(grid, "\n Print statement 2(function print statement)")



print(sudoku_grid, "\n Print statement 1(Original grid b/f function)")
print("________________________")
x = solve(sudoku_grid)
print("________________________")
print(x, "\n Print statement 3")
print("________________________")
print(sudoku_grid, "\n Print statement 4")
```

Comment: Is the grid being returned by the function?

Answer (score 0):

According to your function `solve`, your code either:

- returns a grid, or
- prints a grid

Notice the `return` happens inside `for` cycle, and the print is after it. If the function had returned, no print would happen.

You never reach this part of code:

```
# if no numbers are 0 then Solved and return array
return grid
```

and that's because you're making a recursion without a condition:

```
# Recursion moves to next cell
solve(grid)
```

Notice that

```
        # if cell is zero then tries to enter number
        if grid[i, j] == 0:
            for k in range(1, 10):
               ...
               solve(grid)
               ...
            # if no numbers are 0 then Solved and return array
            return grid
```

is itself incoherent, because you're entering a condition where a 0 cell exists, but you expect a return if none is 0... and even if that would happen, the order of your statements will not let the grid to be returned, because a call to `solve` is being done before the return statement.

So, you must have a condition that will make you not call `solve` and return the grid instead - both in same scope/condition will not work.

Comment: I think it's too early for me to move to backtracking and recursion, because I didn't understand anything you just said. As I said earlier I'm a beginner. I think I'll do a little more research on how these concepts actually work. I now understand there was a flaw in my logic flow.

Comment: Maybe I also did not explain the better way. But research about how to apply recursion to code and you'll understand what I say. I would say the most important is you're missing a **stopping condition** in your recursion - check it out.